# Find out how many times a specific function is used in command line terminal

Tags: command-line, functions

Is there a function to show how many times a specified function has been used?  For example if I wanted to know how many times I had used the cp function or whatever?

Comment: Do you want something specific for functions or all commands? And how far back does it need to go?

Comment: In this specific case I'll be using it to see how many times I have used man but would be useful to be able to apply to other things.  I guess the most useful would be just since the terminal was launched.

Comment: What terminal? Only the specific terminal you are using at the moment?

Comment: Sorry (really new to this) just the built in one in Ubuntu.

Comment: No worries, we were all new once! Yes, I get that it's the default terminal but do you mean to count the times you used `man` only since opening this specific terminal window you are currently using? Basically, there is the `history` command which lists the last N commands you have run, but it isn't per-terminal, it's global across all terminals (and across reboots). So I am trying to understand if that will do for you or if you need something else.

Comment: Oh good question.  I hadn't considered that.  If there is a way to count it only since the current open terminal window was opened that would be useful.  In fairness I wont be using multiple but I think I would at least be looking for something that doesn't carry over from reboots etc.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention I am aware of the history command but as far as my understanding goes, this just shows as a list in the order the commands were done so I would then have to count them.  I was more looking for something which would result in something like man = 12  or even just the number of times itself.

Answer (score 1):

Bash keeps a history of the last N commands you have run in `~/.bash_history` (by default, see the value of `$HISTFILE`) and you can see this list by running `history`:

```
 $ history | head
    1  test.py file.txt outf
    2  cat outf 
    3  test.py file.txt outf
    4  cat outf 
    5  test.py file.txt outf
    6  cat outf 
    7  cat file.t
    8  cat file.txt 
    9  rm file.tex 
   10  test.py file.txt outf
```

Those are the first 10 commands in my history. As you can see, the format is "command number" followed by the actual command. So, to count the times you have used `man`, you could do:

```bsh
history | awk '$2=="man"' | wc -l
```

That will run `history`, `awk` which here will print only those lines whose second field is `man`, and then pass these lines to `wc` which counts them. If you need to run this often, you could make it into a little function. just add these lines to `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
countCom(){
    history | awk -vcom="$@" '$2==com' | wc -l
}
```

Then, to count `man`, you would do:

```
$ countCom man
4460
```

However, this will count the number of times you have run `man` in the entire history of your shell. It isn't only since opening the current terminal. This is usually what you want since seeing just the handful of commands you've run since opening *this* terminal is rarely if ever helpful. After all, those are a subset of the whole.

If you *really* need this to be per-terminal, you could run `history -c` when you open a new terminal. This will clear the history for this terminal so that next time you run `history`, you will only see the commands since opening this terminal.

Unfortunately, you cannot add the `history -c` command to your shell's initialization files (`~/.bashrc` for example) because the history is read after reading the init file, so it has no effect there. So if you really need the history for this terminal and this terminal only, you will have to run `history -c` manually.

Comment: Thanks very much this is really helpful

Comment: @True_False_AX10M see the updated answer, I added a way to make it into a function to be run more easily.